# How to call and run java class method in my jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have tried calling my java method with the code provided below in my jsp file. I am working in a maven project.

The error I am facing is unable to compile class for JSp. How do i resolve it?
How do I call my class methods from JSP?

The code below in my index.jsp file

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <% 
        Test t = Test new Test();
        t.test();
     %>

<h2 style="color:red" align="center">Blog</h2>

<div align="center">

    <h4> Add new user</h4>

    <input class="myTextBox" type="text" placeholder="Enter username"><br/><br/>
    <input class="myTextBox" type="password" placeholder="Enter password"><br/><br/>
    <Button> Add user </Button>

</div>

</body>
```

This is my java code.

```
public class Test {

    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("My name is ");
    }

}
```

Error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\saryal\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\magpie\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The import Test cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Test cannot be resolved to a type
10: 
11:     <body>
12:         <% 
13:             Test t = Test new Test();
14:             t.test();
15:          %>
16:          


An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression
10: 
11:     <body>
12:         <% 
13:             Test t = Test new Test();
14:             t.test();
15:          %>
16:          


An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
10: 
11:     <body>
12:         <% 
13:             Test t = Test new Test();
14:             t.test();
15:          %>
16:          


An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Test cannot be resolved to a variable
10: 
11:     <body>
12:         <% 
13:             Test t = Test new Test();
14:             t.test();
15:          %>
16:          


An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Test cannot be resolved to a type
10: 
11:     <body>
12:         <% 
13:             Test t = Test new Test();
14:             t.test();
15:          %>
16:          


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.26 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

> An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>
> Test cannot be resolved to a type

```
 Test t = Test new Test();//the problem with this statement

 <%
 Test t = new Test();//should be, object will be created
 t.test();
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue pointed out by Satya you may have to add a page directive to your JSP with an import statement. Something like that:

```
<%@ page import="your.package.Test" %>
```